# AngularJS how to get and edit calculated input ng-model value related to other input value

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make some currency exchange system SPA based on AngularJS.

There should be several inputs that get currency data from json (with ng-repeat) and convert currency rate depending on active input value.

```js
{
    "currencies": [
            {
                "name":"EUR", 
                "rate": 1,
                "active": "no"
            },{
                "name": "PLN",
                "rate": 4.1028,
                "active": "no"
            }, {
                "name": "USD",
                "rate": 1.1239,
                "active": "no"
            }
        ]
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat='cur in main.currencies'>
        <label>{{cur.name}}</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" 
            ng-model="cur.result" 
            ng-init='cur.result = ""'
            ng-click='main.clear();'
            ng-focus='main.active = cur; cur.active = true';
            ng-blur='cur.active = false';
        >
</div>
```

How could I input 1 value on active (focused) input and get calculated values on other inputs. I am very new to AngularJS and want to learn it with practical exercises.

Other values should follow such logic: `cur.value = main.active.value / main.active.rate * cur.rate`.

But if I try instead of `ng-model="cur.result"`:

```
ng-model="cur.result = main.active ? cur.result : cur.result/main.active.rate*cur.rate"
```

I can't write anything in input

Maybe I miss some `ng*...` in input properties, but as far I know if I use `ng-model` I should not use `ng-name` and `ng-value`...

Comment: Please add plunkar code.I'll check it

Comment: It's too difficult to do this in plunkr, I created git https://github.com/Skaidrius/currency-ng this html is in https://github.com/Skaidrius/currency-ng/blob/master/app/convert/converse.html.

Comment: http://rawgit.com/Skaidrius/currency-ng/master/index.html shows demo how it is (not) working

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/rzRqBHJbfIyXj5l6Irij?p=preview
Check here

Comment: ng-model references an object. that object can be passed to a function or method. you might use ng-focus to call a fn that sets the rate for the model. i.e. ng-focus="setRate(cur.result);" the function would be defined on the scope from an angular controller. I'll take a stab below.

Answer (score 1):

try this JS:

```
angular.module('app',[]);
angular.module('app').controller('RateCtrl', RateCtrl);
function RateCtrl($scope){
    var vm = $scope;
    vm.cur = {};
    vm.currencies = {/* your object */}
    vm.setRate = function(model, rate){
      return // your javascript 
    }
}
```

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="RateCtrl as main">
    <div ng-repeat="currency in main.currencies">
        <label>{{currency.name}}</label>
        <!-- Fyi, we are in an ng-repeat so there is an isolated scope. Sometimes '$parent.' must come before the objects outside ng-repeat -->
        <input ng-model="main.cur.result" ng-focus="main.setRate(main.cur.result, currency.rate)">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is one very basic way to manipulate the ng-model object. Alternatives include using Angular's filters, watchers, or decorators.

Comment: Let me know if you want help with the actual setRate fn. I assume you know javascript well enough and want to become more aware of the Angular way.

Comment: As far I understand your fn fires when some one clicks input. But I need to let focused input value be the same as user writes and only change values of other inputs. How to select not focused inputs...?

Comment: what about putting all the models in an array, then pop the active one out of the array, leaving only the non-active models in the list to do things to?

Comment: I was thinking about it, but it would be more JS way, not AngularJS :)

Comment: OK, my converter is finaly working and getting actual json data from fixer.io :) I went on a bit different way as I planned. You can check it working here rawgit.com/Skaidrius/currency-ng/master/index.html or a pure code in github, if you write in address above github.com instead of rawgit.com.